# Fastlane with Compose - [!] No screenshots were detected ❌

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, fastlane, screen-grab

Is there a working example of using Jetpack Compose with Fastlane screenshots?

When I try it, I get a "No screenshots were detected" error.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ScreenshotTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Before
    fun init() {
        Screengrab
            .setDefaultScreenshotStrategy(
                UiAutomatorScreenshotStrategy()
            )
    }

    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        Screengrab.screenshot("before");

        composeTestRule.setContent {
            FastlaneTestTheme {
                MainScreen()
            }
        }

        Screengrab.screenshot("after");
    }
}
```

[repo](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/fastlane-test/tree/34989052d3ae8475fcbbe4c26ce0f04322013d3a)

```
_@_-MacBook-Pro FastlaneTest % ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
56 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 52 up-to-date
_@_-MacBook-Pro FastlaneTest % bundle exec fastlane screenshots
[✔]  
[12:38:54]: ------------------------------
[12:38:54]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[12:38:54]: ------------------------------
[12:38:54]: Driving the lane 'android screenshots' 
[12:38:54]: -----------------------------------------
[12:38:54]: --- Step: capture_android_screenshots ---
[12:38:54]: -----------------------------------------
[12:38:54]: Successfully loaded '/Users/_/AndroidStudioProjects/FastlaneTest/fastlane/Screengrabfile' 

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|           Detected Values from './fastlane/Screengrabfile'            |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| test_instrumentation_runner | androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     Summary for screengrab 1.0.0                      |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| tests_package_name          | com.test.fastlane.test                  |
| android_home                | /Users/_/Library/Android/sdk     |
| locales                     | ["en-US"]                               |
| clear_previous_screenshots  | false                                   |
| output_directory            | fastlane/metadata/android               |
| skip_open_summary           | false                                   |
| app_package_name            | com.test.fastlane                       |
| test_instrumentation_runner | androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner |
| ending_locale               | en-US                                   |
| device_type                 | phone                                   |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+

[12:38:54]: Limiting the test classes run by `screengrab` to just those that generate screenshots can make runs faster.
[12:38:54]: Consider using the :use_tests_in_classes or :use_tests_in_packages option, and organize your tests accordingly.
[12:38:54]: $ adb devices -l
[12:38:54]: ▸ List of devices attached
[12:38:54]: ▸ emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone64_arm64 model:sdk_gphone64_arm64 device:emu64a transport_id:2
[12:38:54]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE
[12:38:54]: ▸ /sdcard
[12:38:54]: Cleaning screenshots on device
ls: /sdcard/com.test.fastlane/screengrab: No such file or directory
[12:38:54]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/com.test.fastlane/app_screengrab: Permission denied
[12:38:54]: Exit status: 1
[12:38:54]: To not be asked about this value, you can specify it using 'app_apk_path'
[12:38:54]: Select your debug app APK
1. app/build/intermediates/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
2. app/build/intermediates/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
3. app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
4. app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
?  4
[12:39:00]: To not be asked about this value, you can specify it using 'tests_apk_path'
[12:39:00]: Select your debug tests APK
1. app/build/intermediates/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
2. app/build/intermediates/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
3. app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
4. app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
?  3
[12:39:02]: Validating app APK
[12:39:02]: $ /Users/_/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/34.0.0/aapt dump permissions app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[12:39:02]: ▸ package: com.test.fastlane
[12:39:02]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD'
[12:39:02]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
[12:39:02]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
[12:39:02]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
[12:39:02]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION'
[12:39:02]: ▸ permission: com.test.fastlane.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION
[12:39:02]: ▸ uses-permission: name='com.test.fastlane.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION'
[12:39:02]: Installing app APK
[12:39:02]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 install -r app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[12:39:02]: ▸ Performing Streamed Install
[12:39:03]: ▸ Success
[12:39:03]: Installing tests APK
[12:39:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 install -r app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
[12:39:03]: ▸ Performing Streamed Install
[12:39:03]: ▸ Success
[12:39:03]: Granting the permission necessary to change locales on the device
[12:39:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant com.test.fastlane android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
[12:39:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
[12:39:03]: ▸ 34
[12:39:03]: Granting the permissions necessary to access device external storage
[12:39:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant com.test.fastlane android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
[12:39:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant com.test.fastlane android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
[12:39:03]: Running tests for locale: en-US
[12:39:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument --no-window-animation -w \
-e testLocale en_US \
-e endingLocale en_US \
com.test.fastlane.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
[12:39:05]: ▸ com.test.fastlane.ScreenshotTest:s_glBindAttribLocation: bind attrib 0 name position
[12:39:05]: ▸ s_glBindAttribLocation: bind attrib 1 name color
[12:39:05]: ▸ s_glBindAttribLocation: bind attrib 2 name localCoord
[12:39:06]: ▸ .
[12:39:06]: ▸ Time: 1.45
[12:39:06]: ▸ OK (1 test)
[12:39:06]: Pulling captured screenshots from the device
ls: /sdcard/com.test.fastlane/screengrab: No such file or directory
[12:39:06]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/com.test.fastlane/app_screengrab: Permission denied
[12:39:06]: Exit status: 1
[12:39:06]: Make sure you've used Screengrab.screenshot() in your tests and that your expected tests are being run.
+----------------------------------------+
|              Lane Context              |
+------------------+---------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | android             |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | android             |
| LANE_NAME        | android screenshots |
+------------------+---------------------+
[12:39:06]: No screenshots were detected ❌

+--------------------------------------------------+
|                 fastlane summary                 |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                      | Time (in s) |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform            | 0           |
|    | capture_android_screenshots | 11          |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------+

[12:39:06]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] No screenshots were detected ❌
```

There is an [old issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/17084), but there are also [recent articles](https://www.sinasamaki.com/automating-beautiful-screenshots-using-jetpack-compose/) about framing screenshots.

---

✅ fastlane environment ✅

#### Stack

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| OS | 14.2.1 |
| Ruby | 2.6.10 |
| Bundler? | true |
| Git | git version 2.43.0 |
| Installation Source | /usr/local/bin/fastlane |
| Host | macOS 14.2.1 (23C71) |
| Ruby Lib Dir | /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib |
| OpenSSL Version | LibreSSL 3.3.6 |
| Is contained | false |
| Is homebrew | false |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false |
| Xcode Path | /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ |
| Xcode Version | 15.1 |
| Swift Version | 5.9.2 |

#### System Locale

| Variable | Value |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LANG | en_US.UTF-8 | ✅ |
| LC_ALL |  |  |
| LANGUAGE |  |  |

#### fastlane files:

`./fastlane/Fastfile`

```rb
# This file contains the fastlane.tools configuration
# You can find the documentation at https://docs.fastlane.tools
#
# For a list of all available actions, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
#
# For a list of all available plugins, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/available-plugins
#

# Uncomment the line if you want fastlane to automatically update itself
# update_fastlane

default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  lane :screenshots do
    capture_android_screenshots
    # upload_to_play_store
  end

  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Crashlytics Beta"
  lane :beta do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    crashlytics
  
    # sh "your_script.sh"
    # You can also use other beta testing services here
  end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"
  lane :deploy do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    upload_to_play_store
  end
end
```

`./fastlane/Appfile`

```rb
json_key_file("") # Path to the json secret file - Follow https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/#setup to get one
package_name("com.test.fastlane") # e.g. com.krausefx.app
```

#### fastlane gems

| Gem | Version | Update-Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fastlane | 2.217.0 | ✅ Up-To-Date |
| screengrab | 1.0.0 | ✅ Up-To-Date |

#### Loaded fastlane plugins:

**No plugins Loaded**

**Loaded gems**

| Gem | Version |
| --- | --- |
| did_you_mean | 1.3.0 |
| bundler | 1.17.2 |
| etc | 1.0.1 |
| forwardable | 1.2.0 |
| rake | 13.1.0 |
| rexml | 3.2.6 |
| CFPropertyList | 3.0.6 |
| public_suffix | 5.0.4 |
| addressable | 2.8.6 |
| artifactory | 3.0.15 |
| atomos | 0.1.3 |
| aws-eventstream | 1.3.0 |
| aws-partitions | 1.873.0 |
| aws-sigv4 | 1.8.0 |
| jmespath | 1.6.2 |
| aws-sdk-core | 3.190.1 |
| aws-sdk-kms | 1.75.0 |
| aws-sdk-s3 | 1.142.0 |
| babosa | 1.0.4 |
| claide | 1.1.0 |
| colored | 1.2 |
| colored2 | 3.1.2 |
| highline | 2.0.3 |
| commander | 4.6.0 |
| declarative | 0.0.20 |
| digest-crc | 0.6.5 |
| unf_ext | 0.0.9.1 |
| unf | 0.1.4 |
| domain_name | 0.5.20190701 |
| dotenv | 2.8.1 |
| emoji_regex | 3.2.3 |
| excon | 0.108.0 |
| faraday-em_http | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-em_synchrony | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-excon | 1.1.0 |
| faraday-httpclient | 1.0.1 |
| multipart-post | 2.3.0 |
| faraday-multipart | 1.0.4 |
| faraday-net_http | 1.0.1 |
| faraday-net_http_persistent | 1.2.0 |
| faraday-patron | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-rack | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-retry | 1.0.3 |
| ruby2_keywords | 0.0.5 |
| faraday | 1.10.3 |
| http-cookie | 1.0.5 |
| faraday-cookie_jar | 0.0.7 |
| faraday_middleware | 1.2.0 |
| fastimage | 2.3.0 |
| gh_inspector | 1.1.3 |
| jwt | 2.7.1 |
| multi_json | 1.15.0 |
| os | 1.1.4 |
| signet | 0.18.0 |
| googleauth | 1.8.1 |
| httpclient | 2.8.3 |
| mini_mime | 1.1.5 |
| trailblazer-option | 0.1.2 |
| uber | 0.1.0 |
| representable | 3.2.0 |
| retriable | 3.1.2 |
| webrick | 1.8.1 |
| google-apis-core | 0.11.2 |
| google-apis-androidpublisher_v3 | 0.54.0 |
| google-apis-playcustomapp_v1 | 0.13.0 |
| google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 | 0.17.0 |
| google-apis-storage_v1 | 0.29.0 |
| google-cloud-env | 1.6.0 |
| google-cloud-errors | 1.3.1 |
| google-cloud-core | 1.6.1 |
| google-cloud-storage | 1.45.0 |
| json | 2.7.1 |
| mini_magick | 4.12.0 |
| naturally | 2.2.1 |
| optparse | 0.1.1 |
| plist | 3.7.0 |
| rubyzip | 2.3.2 |
| security | 0.1.3 |
| simctl | 1.6.10 |
| terminal-notifier | 2.0.0 |
| unicode-display_width | 2.5.0 |
| terminal-table | 3.0.2 |
| tty-screen | 0.8.2 |
| tty-cursor | 0.7.1 |
| tty-spinner | 0.9.3 |
| word_wrap | 1.0.0 |
| nanaimo | 0.3.0 |
| xcodeproj | 1.23.0 |
| rouge | 2.0.7 |
| xcpretty | 0.3.0 |
| xcpretty-travis-formatter | 1.0.1 |

*generated on:* **2023-12-24**